# Calculate Decibel from amplitude - Android media recorder

Tags: android, audio, decibel

How to calculate decibel from maxAmplitude, I wrote an android application to get maxAmplitude at regular interval, I need to show the o/p to the user in decibels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Decibels are a *relative* unit, they express the power of your signal relative to some reference power.

If you are working with amplitudes, then the formula is:

```
power_db = 20 * log10(amp / amp_ref);
```

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel#Field_quantities).

Note also that maximum amplitude is not usually a very good indicator of loudness (or even of power).  More typically, you should measure the [*RMS power*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_power) of your signal, and convert that to dB instead.

Comment: what's amp_ref in this formula?

Comment: @Sharj: Your reference amplitude.  Decibels are a relative unit, not absolute.  They express a ratio relative to some reference level.  It's up to you to choose a reference level.

Comment: If the units are amplitudes the multiplier is 20. If the units are power the multiplier is 10.

Comment: @Sharj: One example of reference level is the peak signal amplitude of 0.447V used in consumer electronics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level. Therefore, -6dB decrease is equivalent to a decrease by 2 in the signal amplitude.

Comment: @Alexander:i m trying to generate tone in decibels by giving mobile MediaPlayer volume or amplitude,
is it possible?

Comment: here I am calculating db=(int) (20 * Math.log(((double) maxAmplitude) / 32767d))

Answer (score 7):

Regular phone microphones aren't calibrated to measure absolute loudness, so it's not possible without also having a sound meter to initially calibrate the phone. As Oli mentions, you may be able to calculate a relative change in loudness, but I expect you want to replicate a real sound level meter.