# How to find decibel level in the recorded audio sound

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have recorded audio sound into buffer using wp7.1 application.

I want to find the decibel level in the recorded audio sound.

Please suggest us, how to find it.

Comment: This doesn't look WP7 specific but a question about converting audio buffer values to decibels: as such it looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571894/calculate-decibel-from-amplitude-android-media-recorder

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a reading of the actual decibel level. Among other things there is going to be variance in teh sensativity of microphones in the phones and so on. At most you can only get a relative sound level.

Comment: How can we get a relative sound level ?