# Android: Amplitude value to Decibel value?

Tags: android, microphone, android-sensors, decibel, amplitude

I'm trying to get the decibel of noise being recored from mic on Android phone. I can get amplitude value and looking for the formula to convert it into decibel.

I use following function of MediaRecorder to get amplitude.

> mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() ;

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571894/calculate-decibel-from-amplitude-android-media-recorder) I found the following formula.

> power_db = 20 * log10(amp / amp_ref);

`amp` is amplitude but not sure what's `amp_ref`.

Is there anyone knows the correct formula?

Comment: try 2700.0 as amp_ref.. that may give a strange value
but might work

Comment: @PrateekYadav Where you took that number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that is the correct formula. amp_ref is reference amplitude

Comment: its something you define yourself. you just need a value to compare to (like a base value). read this, might be clearer: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/DB_Display.html