# Android - Calculate deciBel from sound volume

Tags: java, android, audio, android-emulator, android-ndk

Is it possible to calculate the decibel value from the sound volume level?
Suppose a sound is playing, (it could be any track, but I'm using a generated sound with AudioTrack). While the sound is playing, the volume of the sound is increased from 0 (mute) to 99 (maximum).
Now I want to retrieve the decibel value, when the volume level is 50, for example.
Is it possible?

I found how to calculate decibel value in this thread: [Calculate Decibel from amplitude - Android media recorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571894/calculate-decibel-from-amplitude-android-media-recorder)

```
power_db = 20 * log10(amp / amp_ref);
```

but here it uses the amplitude, not sound volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your calculations, you can probably assume that more amplitude = more volume.

They're very closely related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_(sound)

Comment: OK, I will try this. Then what will be `amp_ref` equal with, in this formula?

Comment: You'll have to choose one - decibels are a relative measure of volume, not an absolute measure. Try 30dB as a baseline, and adjust as necessary.

Comment: I still don't get it... 
Lets assume: amp = 50, and amp_ref = 30 (as you pointed out). 
Then db=20*log10(amp/amp_ref), would be equal with = 0. This seems to look not correct.  
The main concern is that, the client wants to increase at every 2 seconds the intensity of tone with 10 decibels, starting from -10 till 100. 
By the way, is this possible to simulate?